# error SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'DBPROYECTO.dbo.Productos'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: c#, sql-server

well so im having this error SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'DBPROYECTO.dbo.Productos'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

the problem is that in my code iam giving a value to "ID", it is not null. Im trying to insert some values into an sql fatabase using c#. while i insert them i get that error. ID is a primary key and of course it cant be null, but the problem is that im actually adding a value to ID so i dont know why i get the error. heres my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsolaCodeFirst
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Modelo.Producto producto = new Modelo.Producto
            {
                ID = 3,
                Nombre = "Monitor",
                Precio = 12500
            };
            DAL.Producto dalProducto = new DAL.Producto();
            dalProducto.Agregar(producto);

            Console.WriteLine($"{producto.Nombre} grabado en la base de datos!");

            Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla para ver los productos");
            Console.ReadKey();
            foreach (var item in dalProducto.TraerTodos())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID} {item.Nombre}  {item.Precio}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class Producto
    {
        Modelo.Contexto contexto = new Modelo.Contexto();

        public void Agregar(Modelo.Producto producto)
        {
            contexto.Productos.Add(producto);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
     }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Modelo
{
    [Table("Productos")]
    public class Producto
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double Precio { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i forgot about my sql database code create database DBPROYECTO;

use DBPROYECTO;

drop table Productos;

create table Productos(
ID int primary key,
Nombre varchar(20) not null,
Precio decimal not null
);

Comment: nvvm i fixed it just by adding [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] to public int ID {get ; set; }